# Legal Navigation Bar Button with image for iOS7

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, user-interface

I could add a custom image to my `UINavigationBar`, but after I read the Human Interface Guidelines about the nav bar icons I'm not sure that my solution is legal. Apple stated that the icon sizes must be 44 x 44px and 22 x 22 px.

Actually I'm using only a 44 x 44 px png in my Nav bar, and it's not so nice. I think it's a bit bigger than it should be.

I'm using this solution actually:

```
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"];

CGRect imageFr = CGRectMake(0, 0, 28,28);

UIButton *sampleButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:imageFr];

[sampleButton setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[sampleButton addTarget:self action:@selector(sampleMethod)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem *button =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:sampleButton];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = button;
```

Do I need to use a 22 x 22 px icon too for the non retina devices? (Actually it looks the same on iPhone 4 and 5 as I see, but these icons are too small, a tiny difference is possible, but I can't see it).

If it's not a recommended way, is it possible to do it in interface builder, without coding the UI elements and set the 22 x 22 px icon too?

Comment: These are *guidelines*, you don't have to follow them exactly, but in some cases they are useful in creating an app that is visually pleasing. If you feel that your icon looks better smaller than their recommended 44x44px, then use your own icon. Nobody at Apple is going to hunt you down for doing it.

Comment: Thank you @max_, what do you think, if I use only the 44 x 44 px image is ok too?

Comment: @rokjarc I didn't intend to say there weren't retina iPads.  I intended to say that there weren't non-retina iPhone/iPods (which support iOS7).

Comment: @nhgrif: i misunderstood you, i guess :)

Comment: @vv88: you can go with smaller icons - no worries there. You might still want to use 44x44 image with a smaller (visual) content and a bit more transparency around, if you want.

Comment: @rokjarc Good idea, thanks. I think I'll keep the 44x44x px and change the CGrect to `0,0,25,25`. But I don't really understand what do you mean on a "bit more transparency around..", I'm using png with transparent bg, do I need to set some other options to?

Comment: that's what i meant: you can keep your smaller image at exactly the same pixel size as it already is and simply extend the transparent background if you want: the bottom line is: Apple will not reject your app because of this unless you icons would really be to small to function properly.